# Changing Variable In Block in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block

I have a problem. I want to change a local variable in a block. I tried everything. I put start of variable __block but there is nothing to change.I can't change the myString Value in block. Could you help me ? Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)setButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    placeName = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] retain];
    __block NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

    [previousParkingLon addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.longitude]];
    [previousParkingLat addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.latitude]];
    [previousParkingsDate addObject:dateString];
    if((self.latitude != 0) && (self.longitude != 0))
    {
        self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init ];
        [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            CLPlacemark *myplacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *locatedAt = [[[myplacemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
            [myString setString:locatedAt];
        }];
    }
        [previousParkingsPlaceName addObject:placeName];
    NSLog(@"Test %@",myString);
        [defaults setObject:previousParkingLat forKey:@"historyLat"];
        [defaults setObject:previousParkingLon forKey:@"historyLon"];
        [defaults setObject:previousParkingsDate forKey:@"historyDate"];
        [defaults setObject:previousParkingsPlaceName forKey:@"historyName"];


        [defaults synchronize];

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: And could mark the line(s) of code that are giving you trouble.

Comment: you don't even need `__block` because the variable did not get assigned to other value. also the problem is you print the value of `myString` before the block is executed

Answer (score 1):

As you are executing the block when `self.geocoder` is done with its action, `locatedAt` is being appended to `myString` after you are outputting `myString` with `NSLog` (iOS doesn't execute the block before moving on). You'll notice that if you put `NSLog` inside the block, the value will be output successfully.

If you want to use the value of `myString` to perform an action, you have two options. The first would be to include the code that utilizes `myString` inside the block, or place it in a function and call that function from within the block. Do not place the code directly after the block! Your second option would be to check to see if the block has executed before using the value of `myString`. Create a boolean with a global scope, and then set the value of the bool to YES in the block. Then you can check to see if the bool is set to YES before utilizing the value of `myString`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to use myString value on the outside. Could you help me about that ?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: Really Thank you. I'm working on this problem 4 hours but i didn't solve it :(

Comment: Let me know if the edit helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried creating a new function for changing but i didn't change the variable.  -(void) changeString: (NSString *) value{
    [placeName setString:value];
}

Comment: Did it work? Or are you still having a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your help Jack :). I understand the problem. The problem is that block and normal program execute asynchronously. I made my other of works in the inside of the block :)

Comment: No problem. Could you please click the check mark next to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the Geocoder executes its completion block ''asynchronously''. The block will not have run by the time the rest of the method is run.

p.s. The `__block` would be unnecessary anyway because you are not assigning to the `myString` variable anywhere